# NSIndexPath in commitEditingStyle

Tags: ios, uitableview

In the commitEditingStyle tableView method, the ".row" property is not working on the NSIndexPath.  Any ideas?

Here is the call

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    NSLog(@" Delete button pushed. IndexPath:%@",indexPath);  
}}
```

When the delete button is pushed in third row of the table the log message is:

'Delete button pushed. IndexPath: 2 indexes [0, 2]'

If I change the log message to:

```
NSLog(@" Delete button pushed. IndexPath.row:%@",indexPath.row);
```

I get a compile error.  What gives?  I thought the NSIndexPath had a 'row' property. Obviously when I check the indexPath, it is there.

Kurt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your format specifier. `row` property is of integer type so you need to use `%d` instead of `%@`.

The `.row` property is part of the extension category defined in `UIKit`.

The doc is in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html.

```
**row**

An index number identifying a row in a section of a table view. (read-only)

@property(readonly) NSUInteger row

**Discussion**

The section the row is in is identified by the value of section.
```